# Cannot display data after checked in checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need advice because I'm still new in PHP, I try to get data from checkbox which is the data is from databases, so when I checked them and press the button it will show the data that I choose, there is no error but the data that I choose it cannot show. This the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<!-- code to show db data with chechbox-->
<form method="post">
  <?php
      include "db_connect.php";

      $sql_select = $dt_bas->prepare("SELECT id_pegawai, nm_pegawai, tmp_lahir FROM pegawai");
      $sql_select->execute();

      while($row = $sql_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $id =  $row["id_pegawai"]; // id
                $nm =  $row["nm_pegawai"]; // employe name
                $tmp = $row["tmp_lahir"]; // birthday
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="select_DB[]" id="select_DB[]" /><?php echo "$id"."</br>";?>


<?php    } ?>

<input type="submit"  value="Test">
</form>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Processing code:

```
<?php
 // this code for get the data that is chosen from checkbox
include "db_connect";

if(isset($_POST['select_DB[]'])){
  $id = $_POST['select_DB[]'];
  $sql_select2 = $db_bas->prepare("SELECT id_pegawai, nm_pegawai,   tmp_lahir FROM pegawai WHERE id_pegawai = '$id' ");
  $sql_select2->execute();

  while($row = $sql_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $id =  $row["id_pegawai"]; // id
            $nm =  $row["nm_pegawai"]; // employee name
            $tmp = $row["tmp_lahir"]; // birth place

            echo "$id"." "."$nm"." "."$tmp"."</br>";
          }
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: `select_DB[]` is incorrect usage. The `POST` index is an array so iterate over `$_POST['select_DB']`. You also should set a value. Also see sql injection note above. `id_pegawai = '$id' ` should be `id_pegawai = ?` then bind the `$id` in the execute. Your `echo` also can be simplified `echo "{$id} {$nm} {$tmp}</br>";`.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your advice but could U more specific, where I put $_GET inside my query? I'm sorry because I'm still new in PHP

Comment: @chris85 Where am I must set the value? Thank for your answer

Comment: `$id` is pulled from `$_POST` and then put directly in your query.

Comment: On the `<input`. Everything should be in my comment..

Answer (score 0):

Well there are some things that you're still not doing and preventing this from work (not going to mention about other things like the ones commented above of the injection):

- First you're not adding a 'value' property for the checkbox, therefore there's no value passed. ie:

`<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="select_DB[]" id="select_DB[]" /><?php echo $id; ?> </br>`

- Then the form will redirect to the same script where it's generated (so not sure if the second set of code you have is on the same file or different)
- Also you don't need to write the bracket once the values are passed, you just need to use the name of the variable (it's already an array). ie:

`if(isset($_POST['select_DB'])){`

- As I mentioned this variable is already an array of every checkbox you selected, so you will need to 1) go through the list individually or 2) construct your query so you can retrieve them all in one go. It all depends on what your final goal is.

Hope that this helps you get on route. I would recommend that you learn about debugging using Xdebug so that way you can analyse better where you're failing.

Comment: Thanks for your help (y) @arturo

Answer (score 0):

Try having your  $id as the value in the inputs for the check boxes as shown below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select_DB[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><?php echo $id; ?><br>
```

For the file receiving the data from the form. Loop through the array $_POST['select_DB'] as shown

```
<?php
// this code for get the data that is chosen from checkbox
include "db_connect";

if(isset($_POST['select_DB'])){
   foreach($_POST['select_DB'] as $select=>$option_id){
      $sql_select2 = $db_bas->prepare("SELECT id_pegawai, nm_pegawai,   tmp_lahir FROM pegawai WHERE id_pegawai = '$option_id' ");
      $sql_select2->execute();

      while($row = $sql_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $id =  $row["id_pegawai"]; // id
        $nm =  $row["nm_pegawai"]; // employee name
        $tmp = $row["tmp_lahir"]; // birth place

        echo "$id"." "."$nm"." "."$tmp"."</br>";
      }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @christ_tp Please also make sure you follow what tadam said in his comment. Also mark as answer if correct.